# How to dual boot in Asus Vivobook 15 x512 laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, freeze, nvidia-geforce

I face problem in dual boot

I disable secure boot , fast boot.

When i boot from my USB it shows black screen  , I try with nomodeset , nouveau.modeset=0 but nothing works . Whta should i do now?

My Asus laptop config is  i5-8 gen , 8GB Ram , 256GB SSD, 1TB HDD, 2GB mx250 Graphic card

Comment: Welcome! How did you prepare the USB?

Comment: By using rufus software i boot my usb

Comment: Did you set the bios to boot from usb?

Comment: yes I did and after selecting ubuntu option presses e and did nomodeset but still screen freezes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

dont use rufus. use etcher. make sure you partition your drive while in windows, before anything. dont turn off fast boot. only disable secure boot. make sure your laptop is plugged in. for some reason i kept getting stuck until i kept my laptop plugged in the whole time.when you power on hit esc until boot option shows. i have an asus vivobook

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to AU - please consider editing your question and try explaining a little bit about those listed steps: why not using rufus, what is etcher and where / how do we use it (even some links may do), why to partition only from windows (it is not the only way). Such information would really help OP and any other user stumbling upon this answer to help their situation better.